# ground attacks in three main areas along the Kherson-Mykolaiv frontline

Tags: grammar

> Southern Ukraine: (Kherson Oblast)
>
> Ukrainian forces continued counter-offensive operations in Kherson Oblast on September 13. Ukrainian and Russian sources indicated that Ukrainian forces conducted ***ground attacks in three main areas along the Kherson-Mykolaiv frontline***; northern Kherson Oblast just south of the Dnipropetrovsk Oblast border; western Kherson Oblast along the Inhulets River; and northwest of Kherson City.

[Source](https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-september-13)

---

I'd like to know if the bold part is a noun phrase and the object of the verb "conducted".

I'm not sure about the grammatical construction of the bold part.

Comment: in the three main areas along the x are two prepositional phrases.

Comment: @Lambie I'd like to know if "in the three main areas" is modified adjectively by "along the x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ground attacks** - fighting on the ground (as opposed to air raids). The Ukrainians attacked in three places along the front line between Kherson and Mykolaiv.

**Ground attacks** is a noun phrase and the rest describes where the attacks took place.